# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - 3.11.4 failing to deploy artifacts with below error(which is working good with 3.10.6)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

The deploy maven artifacts is failing with Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - Version 3.11.4(which is working good with 3.10.6) Please suggest for any solution. Which was the same issue reported in Version 3.10.4 and was fixed in 3.10.6 - (old reference - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1442) and which is repeated again with  3.11.4

````
22:50:23  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
22:50:23    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:37)
22:50:23    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:88)
22:50:23    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:171)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
22:50:23    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
22:50:23    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
22:50:23    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
22:50:23    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
22:50:23    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
22:50:23    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
22:50:23    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
22:50:23    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
22:50:23    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
22:50:23  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
22:50:23    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
22:50:23    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
22:50:23    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:35)
22:50:23    ... 19 more
22:50:23  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;```
````

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins Artifactory Plugin 3.11.4 uses [IOUtils.toString(InputStream, Charset)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-), which presented in Apache IOUtils 2.3, April 2012. For some reason, the Maven resolver chose Apache IOUtils below 2.3, which is very old. This may occur due to another Jenkins plugin that utilizes this version.

This [Pull Request](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/pull/516) should fix this issue by using [IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-). The fix will be available in the next release.

As a workaround, you can downgrade to 3.10.6.